# yum install Lmod - no package Lmod available

Tags: linux, centos, command-line, rhel

Trying to install Lmod and I have encountered the following error. Any potential solutions? Thanks.

```
$ sudo yum install Lmod
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
No package Lmod available.
```

Comment: Lmod should be available in the [EPEL](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/) repository, do you have it enabled?

Comment: @VojtechTrefny no I don't, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all
Lmod should be available in your EPEL Repo.
If not loaded then

```
sudo yum -y install epel-release
sudo yum repolist
sudo yum update
sudo yum upgrade
```

Now Install it with

```
sudo yum install Lmod
```

##### If the above method didnt work for you then you can manually Install Lmod with the process Below

You have to manually Install it from the link Below
Instructions are also available.

https://github.com/TACC/Lmod/blob/master/INSTALL

I should work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).